# Batch file DIR to grab only the top 10 results?

Tags: sql-server-2008, batch-file

I need the last modified date of 15 folders containing over 100,000 non-nested files each.  This will be done in a Windows Server 2008 batch file where the output would go to SQL 2008 via `EXEC xp_cmdshell`

Any idea of how to grab the top 5 results without taking a minute per directory?  Something like this where the head would terminate the pipe and cause dir to stop looking?

```
dir /t:w /o:-d /4 *.jpg | head
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't eliminate the delay completely, but at least reduces it to a more bearable one, I think:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET cnt=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" IN ('dir /t:w /o:-d /4 *.jpg') DO (
SET /A cnt+=1
SET "line!cnt!=%%a"
IF !cnt!==10 GOTO break
)
:break
ECHO %line6%
ECHO %line7%
ECHO %line8%
ECHO %line9%
ECHO %line10%
```

Comment: Nice.  I made it to `for /f "skip=4 tokens=1" %a in ('dir /p /t:w /o:-d /4 *.jpg') do @echo %a` prior to your answer.  Still have the 1:10 minute delay on the dir command per folder.  You would think there's some sort of dir | head which terminates after 10 lines or so.

Comment: @Dr. Zim: (*facepalm*) `skip`! Why didn't I think of it? On the other note, I tried this also: `dir | for /L %%a in (1,1,10) do set /p line%%1=` but piped input doesn't seem to work for some reason even though it works fine when it's from a file.